# Nothing Happens When didSelectRowAtIndexPath on table view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a table view and when i select one of the items it should go to my EventsDetailsViewController storyboard for displaying details but nothing happens when i click one of the itmes in my table view.  Below is the code i thought would send a user to the EventsDetailsViewController when selected but doesn't.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EventsDetailsViewController *eventsdetailsViewController = [[EventsDetailsViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"EventsDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    eventsdetailsViewController.title = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"eName"];
    eventsdetailsViewController.eventsArticle = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsdetailsViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Is the method called?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the method. Is it getting hit? Did you set the tableview's delegate?

Comment: i set a break point at each line and they all get hit when i select an item from my tableview just doesnt go to the EventsDetailsViewController

Comment: Is `self.navigationController == nil`?

Comment: how do i tell if its nil?

Comment: @user875293 `if (self.navigationController == nil)`

Comment: In the text of your problem description you mention that EventsDetailsViewController is in a storyboard, yet you are trying to instantiate it from a nib file.  Is it in a storyboard, and do you have a segue from your table view controller to EventsDetailsViewController?

Comment: have you set `tableview` delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problems could be:

1. Your application is not navigation controller based. Just check if you have created a navigation controller through Xib, storyboard, or programatically.
2. Your EventsDetailsViewController is not at all created. Have a break point or log the object and test if this is created or just nil.

You can easily verify both the cases by using the below statements:

```
NSLog("Navigation COntroller %@",self.navigationController);
NSLog("Events COntroller %@", eventsdetailsViewController);
```

Let us assume ABCController is the controller in which the table view delegate methods are present and from there you want to move to the EventsDetailsViewController.
Adding navigation controller to your existing project:

Create a navigation controller object in your app delegate and set this as rootViewController

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: im pretty sure its my application is not navigation controller based how do i resolove this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem of `tableView`, the problem is in `navigationController`, check whether it is nil or something in `debug area`
If it is nil then initialize it.

**Hope this will help you.**

**EDIT :
How to Declare NavigationController**

Add this to `AppDelegate.m` file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ParentViewController *parent = [[ParentViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:parent];
    self.window.rootViewController = myNav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right i just dont know where or how to initialize it?

Comment: @user875293 : Check the edited answer....this is how we initialize navigationController.